# Array of objects for PHP (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

I've been struggling with converting an **Array of objects** to JSON, or any other PHP readable format so I can send it over AJAX.

I'm using localStorage and I save an object into it, I save it using

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Now when I loop through all the localStorage data, I add it to an array using the following code

```
var locations = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    locations[i] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```

The end result looks like this.

[image]

This is my $.ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "store.php",
    dataType: "json", 
    data: locations,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The only problem is that I can't seem to convert it to a readable format to send to PHP

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: What does your PHP look like? Data in that form should be readable.

Comment: I'm currently only printing out the full post request for testing. I'll add the ajax request

Comment: How do you print your data from PHP?

Comment: I'm trying print_r($_POST); but it's not showing anything.

Comment: Maybe you should put your `locations` to an object.

`
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "store.php",
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {location: locations},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
`

Then on your PHP, `print($_POST["location"]);`

Comment: Aha! That's the solution. Didn't know you had to do that.. Thank you! If you post it as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: jQuery should automatically serialize the data if it's an array.

Comment: @Purag jQuery needs key for sending your data, it has to be a JSON object.

Comment: @eurica I was going off of [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) page. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it though!

Comment: @Purag It says `Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below)`.
It means that if the value of your Key/Value pairs is an Array, then jQuery automatically serialize your Array.

Comment: @eurica You're right. Good call. It's kinda late and I'm starting to feel it, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your post data an object.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "store.php",
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {location: locations},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Then on your PHP: `print($_POST['location']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify like this.

```
$.post('store.php', {location: locations}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to pass the content directly from localStorage -- no need to build an array from it.

Data formed with `JSON.stringify()` can be sent through `$.ajax` and interpreted by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's input stream to read your data:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json);
```

For more info on PHP's I/O streams, see http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php